# twitter jsOAuth fetch request token returns 401 error

Tags: twitter, titanium, titanium-mobile, jsoauth

Application type: mobile, 
Titanium SDK: 3.0.2.GA, 
Platform & version: Android 4.0.4, 
Device: Android Xperia P,

i am trying to use twitter API via jsOAuth 1.3.6. all the OAuth dance goes well until I fetch request token (oAuthApi.fetchAccessToken() method). i am always getting "unauthorized" error any idea why? please see code below

```javascript
oAuthApi.fetchRequestToken(function(data) {
                    //authorize
                    var authorizeUi = Ti.UI.createWebView({
                        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
                        height : Ti.UI.FILL,
                        top : 0,
                        left : 0,
                        url : data
                    });
                    authorizeUi.addEventListener('load', function(e) {                            
                        if (authorizeUi.getUrl().indexOf('twitterOauthCallback') > -1) {
                            oAuthApi.fetchAccessToken(function(data) {
                                oAuthApi.saveAccessToken();
                                oAuthApi.setAuthorised(true);
                                var accessToken = oAuthApi.getAccessToken();
                                var accessTokenSecret = oAuthApi.getAccessTokenSecret();

                               ...some other code here

                            }, function(data) {
                                alert('fetchAccessToken unauthorized error ' + data.error);
                            });
                        }
                    });                        

                }, function(data) {
                    alert('fetchRequestToken error');
                });
```

here is my jsOAuth initialization:

```javascript
var oauth = OAuth({
        consumerKey : jsonObj.consumerKey,
        consumerSecret : jsonObj.consumerSecret,
        callbackUrl : jsonObj.callbackUrl
    });
```

my callback is

```
http://192.168.1.116:8888/callback/twitterOauthCallback.html
```

1- I call fetchRequestToken (ok)
2- i open the user authorization / login window (ok)
3 - enter username and password and get the callback url (ok)
4 - call fetchAccessToken (get 401 error)

below is my header:

```
oauth_callback = http://192.168.1.74:8888/callback/twitterOauthCallback.html
oauth_consumer_key = E3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxHfg
oauth_token = J1fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx20
oauth_signature_method = HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp = 1365151792
oauth_nonce = 36222C667E353A51
oauth_verifier = 
oauth_version = 1.0
```

any idea what might be the problem ?? i am blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter made an abrupt and unannounced change to oauth this week: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443

Looking at the header, the issue is that your `oauth_verifier` value is empty and the change now enforces this value. You'll get this with your callback URL as a parameter (`http://192.168.1.116:8888/callback/twitterOauthCallback.html?oauth_token=xxx&oauth_verifier=xxx`)